# jQuery & Backbone: How to append a view on drop event, under certain conditions

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, jquery-droppable, jquery-draggable

I have the following View of my CanvasModel, on which the user can drag & drop various widgets from a toolbar. Whenever something is dropped into the CanvasView a new WidgetView instance will be appended into the DOM.

The recently appended Widget is also draggable, in order for the user to position it wherever he wants within the Canvas. The problem is that as soon as the recently appended Widget is dropped, another WidgetView instance gets appended

```
var CanvasView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName: 'section',
    className: 'canvas', 

    events: {
    'drop': 'instantiateWidget'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.$el.droppable({});
    },

    render: function(){
        return this;
    },

    instantiateWidget: function() {
        this.$el.on("drop", function(event, ui){}).append(new WidgetView({model: myWidget}).render().el);   
    }
});
```

I only want to instantiate a Widget that is dragged from the toolbar to the canvas, (they have a class of "dragged"). Is there a way to "filter" the drop listener, so the  CanvasView will instantiate a Widget only when the dropped item has either a class of "dragged" or it has been dragged from the toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that specific drop event, but to answer your question of

> Is there a way to "filter" the drop listener

The answer is, yes indeed.  All event handlers get passed an event object, and you can check out the details of it (in particular its `target` property) to determine which DOM element triggered the event.

However, I noticed a more important issue in your code: you seem to be hooking up the event handler improperly.  You're doing:

```
this.$el.on("drop", function(event, ui){}).append(new WidgetView({model: myWidget}).render().el);
```

which will hook up an event handler that does nothing, then immediately append a new widget.  What I think you want to do is:

```
this.$el.on("drop", function(event, ui){
    $(event.target).append(new WidgetView({model: myWidget}).render().el)
});
```

Except even that seems wrong, because you're binding an event handler in response to another event.  What I think you want is:

```
instantiateWidget: function() {
   this.$el.append(new WidgetView({model: myWidget}).render().el);   
}
```

So, to circle back to your original question, if you want to check the element that caused the event in that new code, it would look something like:

```
instantiateWidget: function(e) {
   if ($(e.target).is(':not(canvas)') return;
   this.$el.append(new WidgetView({model: myWidget}).render().el);   
}
```

Alternatively, you *might* be able to avoid that entirely and just set your selectors on your event hookups to only target events spawned by the elements you want (remember, the event hookups just use normal jQuery selectors).

Comment: Thankx for your reply. Unfortunately your code example won't run (Unexpected toke this) in the following line
     this.$el.append(new WidgetView({model: myWidget}).render().el);

Answer (score 0):

as @machineghost pointed out, I had a fatal error in my syntax. However from what I understood from the code, we check for the event  target, and if it's not the 'canvas' then nothing happens, while if it is, the widget gets rendered into it.
Unfortunately this is not the case, as the instantiated widgets are also draggable within the canvas (for the user to position them) and even with your implementation i think the drag/dropping of instantiated widgets will as well cause more instantiations in the canvas (as soon as they get dropped).

Essentialy what I would like to do is check if the dragged element from the toolbar has a class of "dragged" (which it does) and if so, only then to instantiate a widget into the canvas, which will prevent the newly instantiated widget to cause further instantiations while it's being dragged around the canvas for positioning (instantiated widgets don't have a class of dragged).

In order to implement something like that, I digged a bit into jQuery events. There's a nice event called "dragstop" which i could use in the following manner to get what I want.

```
$('section#toolbar').children.on("dragstop", function(event, ui){})
```

The problem is that within the function for dragstop, i need to refer to the drop event

```
 if ($(e.target).is('canvas')) this.$el.append(new WidgetCanvasView({model: myWidget}).render().el);
```

But apparently that won't work either... (need to bind events, etc..)
Thanks for your answer though, it got me thinking and digging more in depth into events, and how to bind them etc... Hopefully I will find how to work around this issue!